# What's the project keyword in build definitions?

Tags: sbt

After having read the chapter on [multi-project builds](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Multi-Project.html), I've seen this construct:

```
lazy val util = project
lazy val core = project
```

I wonder what *project* is.  In the API documentation I can see the Project trait and its companion object, but no entry about *project*.  I've thought it could be a member of trait Build, but it isn't either.

The only thing I know, it returns a Project trait. Where can I find it in the API documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`project`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/main/src/main/scala/sbt/Project.scala#L601) is a macro. You can find documentation for it in [ProjectExtra](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/api/#sbt.ProjectExtra), but it's not very verbose.

Basically it will take project's id and directory from the name of the val to which it is assigned.

It may also be used in the form of

```
lazy val util, core = project
```

that would give you a quick (and hopefully easy) way to lay out a multi-project build definition.

Moreover, the `project` macro applies as much to single-project builds as to multi-project ones. It has just appeared more often in multi-project builds since there's much more to configure and `build.sbt`'s alone are usually not enough.